# Check for a unique value inside a collection using LINQ?

Tags: linq

I have the following class definition:

```
public class PriorityItem
{
    public string uniqueID { get; set; }
    public List<DelegationTask> DelegationTasks = new List<DelegationTask>();
    public List<int> Priorities = new List<int>(); 
}
```

Now lets say I create a list from this class like this:

```
List<PriorityItem> pItems = new List<PriorityItem>();
```

And now I want to check for the presence of an item in this list based on the uniqueID property how is this done?

For example I will populate the list with a collection of PriorityItem, but only if the Priority item does not exist. To determine if it exists, I need to check using LINQ the value of uniqueID.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 5):

The Any linq extension method returns true if any items are found which match a certain criteria. You can use it as follows:

```
string idToSearchFor = "123"
bool exists = pItems.Any(item => item.uniqueId == idToSearchFor);
```

With the above code `exists` will be true, only if your list contains a `PriorityItem` with the `uniqueId` of `"123"`.

Answer (score 0):

Exists does the same thing as Any.  Exists matches the SQL parlance a little more than Any does.  Any and All naturally fit together as a kind of natural qualifier *pair*.

However in the sentence, "do we have this unique id?"  Perhaps "exists" is a better fit in terms of readability and intention.

```
class Class1
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        // initialise list
        var pItems = new List<PriorityItem>(){new PriorityItem(){uniqueID = "1"}, new PriorityItem(){uniqueID = "2"}, new PriorityItem(){ uniqueID = "123"}};
        var IDtoFind = "123";
        var wasFound = pItems.Exists(o => o.uniqueID == IDtoFind);
    }
}

public class PriorityItem
{
    public string uniqueID { get; set; }
    //public List<DelegationTask> DelegationTasks = new List<DelegationTask>();
    public List<int> Priorities = new List<int>();

}
```